# How to know which test is throwing after it completes in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have alot of tests in a project. When I run `flutter test`, all the tests pass, but I get this error in the console:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown running a test (but after the test had completed):
Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by
calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      Element._debugCheckStateIsActiveForAncestorLookup.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4241:9)
#1      Element._debugCheckStateIsActiveForAncestorLookup (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4255:6)
#2      Element.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4275:12)
#3      Localizations.of (package:flutter/src/widgets/localizations.dart:472:48)
#4      AppLocalizations.of (package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart:68:26)
#5      ScreenshotCubit._captureWidget (package:photo_editor/ui/screens/editor_screen/bloc/screenshot_cubit/screenshot_cubit.dart:175:51)
<asynchronous suspension>
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

I know the reason of it, a test is trying to get a string from the `AppLocalizations` after the `context` is no longer available (mounted). But the message does not give any info about which test is causing the error. So how can I know which one is it without having to run the tests one by one?

### Update:

I ran the tests in groups and narrowed the problem to one group.

But now when running the tests in the whole group in android studio I get the exception (all the tests pass).

But if I run the same tests one by one, all of them pass, and no one gives this exception.

Can someone explain to me how to solve this?

Comment: Umcomment half of your tests and run them again, if they pass the culprit is in commented tests, if they fail the culprit is here, repeat the above with the found half

Comment: @pskink thx for the hint, I ran them in groups and narrowed down the problematic test into a group, but a weird thing happens now please see the updated question.

Comment: well I would bet there are two tests in your selected group which when run together show the issue - but it is just wild guess

Comment: but in all cases that would be weird,bcz the tests, from this perspective, should be independent of each other.